# "Create table as select" does not preserve not null

Tags: oracle, create-table

I am trying to use the "Create Table As Select" feature from Oracle to do a fast update.  The problem I am seeing is that the "Null" field is not being preserved.

I defined the following table:

```
create table mytable(
  accountname varchar2(40) not null,
  username varchar2(40)
 );
```

When I do a raw CTAS, the NOT NULL on account is preserved:

```
 create table ctamytable as select * from mytable;

 describe ctamytable;

Name        Null     Type         
----------- -------- ------------ 
ACCOUNTNAME NOT NULL VARCHAR2(40)

USERNAME             VARCHAR2(40)
```

However, when I do a replace on accountname, the NOT NULL is not preserved.

```
 create table ctamytable as 
   select replace(accountname, 'foo', 'foo2') accountname, 
          username 
     from mytable;

 describe ctamytable;

Name        Null Type          
----------- ---- ------------- 
ACCOUNTNAME      VARCHAR2(160) 
USERNAME         VARCHAR2(40)
```

Notice that the `accountname` field no longer has a null, and the `varchar2` field went from 40 to 160 characters.  Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are no longer selecting `ACCOUNTNAME`, which has a column definition and meta-data. Rather you are selecting a STRING, the result of the `replace` function, which doesn't have any meta-data. This is a different data type entirely.

A (potentially) better way that might work is to create the table using a query with the original columns, but with a `WHERE` clause that guarantees 0 rows.

Then you can insert in to the table normally with your actual `SELECT`.

By having query of 0 rows, you'll still get the column meta-data, so the table should be created, but no rows will be inserted. Make sure you make your `WHERE` clause something fast, like `WHERE primary_key = -999999`, some number you know would never exist.

Comment: No need to risk matching a row by using a magic number, you can just set the WHERE clause to 1=2.

Comment: Thanks, the explanation of the casting makes sense.  I am trying to do a schema wide comparison, the NOT NULL's not showing up serves as a false positive.  I need to find another way to determine the Null column.

Comment: @Ben yea that what we used to do in the old days, but I'm not sure if it was universally applicable to other databases.

Answer (score 2):

Another option here is to define the columns when you call the CREATE TABLE AS SELECT. It is possible to list the column names and include constraints while excluding the data types.

An example is shown below:

```
create table ctamytable (
  accountname not null,
  username
)
as 
  select 
    replace(accountname, 'foo', 'foo2') accountname, 
    username 
  from mytable;
```

Be aware that although this syntax is valid, you cannot include the data type. Also, explicitly declaring all the columns somewhat defeats the purpose of using CREATE TABLE AS SELECT.

Comment: After reading the question again, I realise that I haven't really solved the original problem you're having but it does provide additional information about the use of CTAS.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  I am doing all of this through Java.  In the end, I store all of the NOT NULL constraints before running CTAS and re-apply them afterwards.